# Overloaded Parenthesis operator with no arguments feature name

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, functor

Wikipedia's article on [Properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_%28programming%29#C.2B.2B) presents a template class that can be used to create property members (lightly edited):

```
template <typename T> class property {
        T value;
    public:
        T & operator = (const T &i) {
            return value = i;
        }

        operator T const & () const {
            return value;
        }
};


struct Bar {
    // Using the property<>-template.
    property <bool> alpha;
    property <unsigned int> bravo;
};

int main () {
    Bar bar;
    bar.alpha = true;

    return bar.bravo;
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is the name of the C++ feature that lets that to `bar.bravo` exist with no trailing `()`.

The code [compiles](http://ideone.com/p2LuJ7) fine... I just have no idea why!

Googling points me to 'Functors', but those overloaded parens operators all seem to have arguments (and I can understand how they work).

Comment: You're confusing the symbol for the operator with the lexical structure of an ordinary function declarations. A "parentheses operator" would be `operator()()`. That's now what we have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
    operator T const & () const {
        return value;
    }
```

Is an [overloaded conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) operator. Because it is not `explicit`, it allows for an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

The class `property<T>` defines an "implicit conversion to `T const &`" operator:

```
operator T const & () const { return value; }
```

So you can convert a value of type `property<T>` to a value of type `T` (more specifically, to a constant lvalue of type `T`).